# How to iterate a mixed of nested list and dict and filter items

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested-loops, literate-programming

I have an example object which is mixed of lists and dicts:

```
{
    "field_1" : "aaa",
    "field_2": [
        {
        "field_3" : "bbb",
          .....
        "field_4" : "ccc",
        "field_need_to_filter" : False,
    },

        {
        "field_5" : "ddd",
          .....
        "field_6": [
            {
            "field_7" : "eee",
            ....
            "field_8" : [
                {
                "field_9": "fff",
                .....
                "field_10": {
                    "field_11": "rrr",
                    ...
                    "field_12": [
                        {
                        "field_13": "xxx",
                        ...
                        "field_need_to_filter": True,
                        },
                        {
                        "field_13": "yyy",
                        ...
                        "field_need_to_filter": True,
                        },
                        {
                        "field_13": "zzz",
                        ...
                        "field_need_to_filter": False,
                        }
                                ]
                                }
                },


        ]}]}

       ]
}
```

I'd like to iterate it and add all the corresponding values for `field_13` where `field_need_to_filter` is `True`, so for this example, expected output would be:
`["xxx", "yyy"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try recursion:

```py
dct = {
    "field_1": "aaa",
    "field_2": [
        {
            "field_3": "bbb",
            "field_4": "ccc",
            "field_need_to_filter": False,
        },
        {
            "field_5": "ddd",
            "field_6": [
                {
                    "field_7": "eee",
                    "field_8": [
                        {
                            "field_9": "fff",
                            "field_10": {
                                "field_11": "rrr",
                                "field_12": [
                                    {
                                        "field_13": "xxx",
                                        "field_need_to_filter": True,
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "field_13": "yyy",
                                        "field_need_to_filter": True,
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "field_13": "zzz",
                                        "field_need_to_filter": False,
                                    },
                                ],
                            },
                        },
                    ],
                }
            ],
        },
    ],
}


def find(o, key):
    if isinstance(o, dict):
        if key in o and o.get("field_need_to_filter"):
            yield o[key]

        for v in o.values():
            yield from find(v, key)
    elif isinstance(o, list):
        for v in o:
            yield from find(v, key)


out = list(find(dct, "field_13"))
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
['xxx', 'yyy']
```

Comment: thanks, i''m trying to wrap `out = list(find(dct, "field_13"))
` and the function above into one single function, all I did is define another function `def build_list(o, key):  out= list(find(o, "key"))    return out` but `out` retruns to be an empty list, am i missing anything here?

Comment: @wawawa `def build_list(o, key):  out= list(find(o, key))` . Don't forget to return `out`

Comment: ah yes it should be without the quote, sorry for being stupid! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks a simple recursive function should do the trick here, see below.

Define data:

```
 data = {
    "field_1" : "aaa",
    "field_2": [
        {
        "field_3" : "bbb",
        "field_4" : "ccc",
        "field_need_to_filter" : False,
    },

        {
        "field_5" : "ddd",
        "field_6": [
            {
            "field_7" : "eee",
            "field_8" : [
                {
                "field_9": "fff",
                "field_10": {
                    "field_11": "rrr",
                    "field_12": [
                        {
                        "field_13": "xxx",
                        "field_need_to_filter": True,
                        },
                        {
                        "field_13": "yyy",
                        "field_need_to_filter": True,
                        },
                        {
                        "field_13": "zzz",
                        "field_need_to_filter": False,
                        }
                                ]
                                }
                },


        ]}]}

       ]
}
```

Filter data:

```
   def FilterData():
    
      results = []
    
      def Filter(data):
        if isinstance(data, list):
          for item in data:
            Filter(item)
        elif isinstance(data, dict):
          if data.get('field_need_to_filter'):
            results.append(data.get('field_13'))
          Filter(list(data.values()))
    
      Filter(data)
      return results
```